# Simplifying this algebraic expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm finding algebraic holes in my knowledge.

Show how you simplify

$$\frac{r-r^3}{1+r}$$

into

$$r(1-r)$$

and please show every step.

Comment: The universal, brute-force way of dealing with this is simply doing polynomial division.

Comment: An important missing point here is that we **must** assume that $r\neq -1$ in all answers above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\frac{r-r^3}{1+r}&=\frac{r(1-r^2)}{1+r}\\
&=\frac{r(1-r^2)}{1+r}\\
&=\frac{r(1-r)(1+r)}{1+r}\\
&=r(1-r)\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: How do you recognise polynomial expressions like that? It feels like I always struggle with them. Is there something to special to look for?

Answer (score 2):

Notice that you can take out a $r$ from the numerator to get:

$$\frac{r ( 1- r^2)}{1+r}$$

Then notice that the numerator is a difference of squares $(a^2-b^2) = (a+b)(a-b)$ and can thus be factored as such

$$\require{cancel} \frac{r (1-r)\cancel{(1+r)}}{\cancel{(1+r)}}$$

Now you can cancel the $(1+r)$ from top and bottom to get:

$$r(1-r)$$

ADD.

The best way to simplify such expressions is to first try and common factor. So, in this case we recognized that $r$ is a common factor in the numerator and therefore, we can take it out. Once you common factor, you can then try see if it is some special case and in this instance it's a difference of squares. Once that happens try and cancel things out and you should be left with the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your great answer, but Jasper was first :)

Comment: @Mattis No problem :) Glad to know that it helped.

Answer (score 1):

In general, any time you want to simply a fraction of two polynomials, you can first factor both polynomials and then eliminate any common factors from the numerator and denominator.  Sometimes this will eliminate the denominator completely, as in your case, but not always.